# Measure for overlapping clusters

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, clustering

I have two different cluster in the spacial domain of N-Dimension. These clusters are overlapped with each other meaning there are several points of a given cluster between several points of the other cluster. So I am looking for a metric to actually measure this overlap. Any idea?
Almost all cluster overlap measurements are set based like Jaccard index nothing spatial distance based which I am looking for.